# Android - Best way to edit .txt file?

Tags: java, android, file, io

I've had a look around and haven't been able to come up with an answer to my issue.

I'm creating a fitness app and it allows users to save different workouts for future use. All the information is saved in txt file on internal storage. I'm trying to now implement a feature to be able to edit these workouts, so my question is:

What is the best way to edit a .txt file in android?
Should I just delete the old entry and save the new one in its place or is there a better way?

Comment: Just save the new one. It will automatically delete the old one.

Comment: Does the user edit the text directly or is it exported by your app?

Comment: Sorry I might not have been clear. It's one file for all the workouts, so I actually want to edit only one line instead of a whole file

Comment: The user never sees the text file, it's just used to save/load workouts for their use, but they never write directly into the text file

Comment: Not really answering your question as such but maybe an alternative: Why don't you use the SQLite DB that Android gives you nearly for free?

Comment: I haven't done any SQL stuff before but I'll look into it as it sounds useful. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only append to a text file (add to the end); any other edit requires that you load the full file in working memory, modify it, and save it a new file (possibly overwriting the old one).

If this sounds like a bad idea (because the files are large and complex) then perhaps you should be looking at using SQLLite facilities which are standard android libraries and designed relatively simple record keeping tasks of this nature.

Unless your data is extremely unusual the SQL path will make for easier, clearer code in the long term.

Comment: I don't have much data in this file so I might go with the open, modify, save but I'll also look into SQL as it sounds useful

Comment: Especially when it gets to the reporting side - when you have you list all the week days I slept less than 6 hours but ran more that 8km the text based solution will be very heavy; the SQL solituon quite straight forward

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have now looked into SQL and my app is working well using a simple SQL database :)

Answer (score 0):

Using SQLite database maybe the best way of saving data for different users. And if you want to edit a text file, you can load the full file in memory and rewrite the file after modify the content.